# can a typescript call implement an interface, and make the vars private?

Tags: interface, typescript

Here's what I'm trying to do. We receive JSON data in the structure of our classes. So we can declare an interface as follows:

```
export interface IElement {
id : number;
name : string;
}
```

And then the class as follows:

```
export class Element implements IElement {
    id : number;
    name : string;

constructor (src : IElement) {
    this.id = src.id;
    this.name = src.name;
    }
}
```

We then cast the JSON data to an <IElement> and pass that to the class constructor. The constructor can then be passed an IElement or an Element and life is good.

However... I want to force access to use a getter and setter. So what I'd like to do is:

```
export class Element implements IElement {
    private id : number;
    private name : string;

constructor (src : IElement) {
    this.id = src.id;
    this.name = src.name;
    }

getId () : number {
    return this.id;
    }
getName () : string{
    return this.name;
    }
}
```

The above would all still work fine for me because in the constructor I'm allowed access to those variables. However, if they are set to private, then Element no longer implements IElement because it does not fulfill the contract in IElement.

Is there a way to do this? If we have to, Element does not have to implement IElement, but it makes life cleaner if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your public surface area is substitutable for the interface, or it isn't. The class cannot substitute for an `IElement` (and it *shouldn't* if you want to force people to use getters!), so it cannot `implement` the interface.

Since you didn't say why you wanted people to use getters, I don't know if this is appropriate or not, but you can use property getters in classes:

```
export interface IElement {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export class Element implements IElement {
    private _id: number;
    private _name: string;
    constructor (src: IElement) {
        this._id = src.id;
        this._name = src.name;
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only workaround. I see that if I do not inject `src: IElement` it gives an error. Is there a way to do something like this >> `export interface IElement {
private id : number;
private name : string;
}`